# Add scrollable panels in the DockPanel Suite

Tags: c#, dockpanel-suite

I am trying to add scroll bars to a panel using the WeiFen Luo Dock Panel Suite (DPS). I have my forms created and the layout is how I want it, however one of my forms is larger than the area I have allocated for one group of panels. Scroll bars on the panel seem like the most logical option, but I cannot get them to be enabled for the form.

I tried setting AutoScroll to True, but this changed nothing. I then added a minimum size constraint, but this caused the panel to show behind other panels and other docking instabilities. Is this a bug, or perhaps am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you just need to set AutoScroll to True and then define an AutoScrollMinSize. Note that there seems to be a bug if you do not make the panel large enough to negate the need for scroll bars in the designer. The bug causes the window to resize in the designer at run-time (In VS 2012 and VS Community 2013).